# how to test project using Android Test Project

Tags: android, unit-testing

i am new in test android project.  just i try to test sample hello world application. its working. i refer the following link

```
 https://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html
```

i have one doubt can i test whole android project using android test? its possible?. otherwise that android test only applicable for small applications. i want to test tabs and web service hitting and lot of functionality using android test project.

any one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit test is possible for android application.if you want to test an android application then you use testing tool like robotium.here you follow this link

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started

Robotium is a test framework created to make it easy to write powerful and robust automatic black-box test cases for Android applications.

Comment: its shoutable for all android project?